# Using Kendo styles without Kendo controls

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm working in an app which relied on some Kendo controls. The client wants to style a few things as they exist now (namely a dropdown). I am creating this select dropdown by hand (angular to populate and control data)

I want to use the same styling provided by Kendo-UI on this dropdown but cannot seem to divorce the Kendo data source from their styling.

How can I apply the k-dropdown and dropdown list styling to my own select?

I've tried mussing with throwing the span wrapper around it. The closest I've been able to get is http://jsfiddle.net/7kcwdvvs/1/

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header">
  <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
    <span class="k-input"></span>
    <span class="k-select">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
      <select class="k-input">
        <option class="k-select">test</option>
      </select>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>

<select class="k-input">
  <option class="k-select">test</option>
</select>
```

Which obviously doesn't work.

1) How can I apply Kendo style directly to my own rolled dropdown select?

Comment: I ended up just wrapping this in a proper kendo control and managing everything with an awkward mix of Angular and JQuery. Would still love an answer if anyone has one...

Comment: How about this http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/ ?

Comment: Using CSS and moving that span that has the arrow under the select can provide [_some sort_ of what you're looking for](http://jsfiddle.net/7kcwdvvs/2/).